# How to choose a Phone Call in Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-phone-call

When I click phone call button, how to choose skype, viber, sim1 or sim2, ect. Now, it is called by sim2. I want to choose. I search on Google, no found my problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Permissions in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Search on google

Comment: I search, all r directly. I don't find. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset App preferences before starting intent

```
Settings->Apps/Application Manager -> Default/Downloaded Apps -> Click on overflow icon (i.e. three dots icon on top right of the screen) -> Reset App Preferences.
```

Your code looks fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How to do (Reset App preferences before starting intent) ?

Comment: In your device, Go to Settings->Apps/Application Manager -> Default/Downloaded Apps -> Click on overflow icon (i.e. three dots icon on top right of the screen) -> Reset App Preferences.

Comment: Also reset dual sim settings and don't set default SIM for SMS or Call

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a sim chooser dialog and set sim 1 and sim 2 options and set simNumber variable according to the choosen sim number(0 for sim1 and 1 for sim2)

Here is the code that I have implemented for calling from specific sim i.e. SIM 1 or SIM 2.

**code:**

```
private final static String simSlotName[] = {
    "extra_asus_dial_use_dualsim",
    "com.android.phone.extra.slot",
    "slot",
    "simslot",
    "sim_slot",
    "subscription",
    "Subscription",
    "phone",
    "com.android.phone.DialingMode",
    "simSlot",
    "slot_id",
    "simId",
    "simnum",
    "phone_type",
    "slotId",
    "slotIdx"
};

int simNumber = 0 or 1; //0 for sim1 and 1 for sim2
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + phoneNumber));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//Add slots here since different device needs different key so put all together
for (String s : simSlotName)
    intent.putExtra(s, simNumber);

//This will only work on API 22 or up
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    intent.putExtra("android.telecom.extra.PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE", (Parcelable) SimSlotHelper.getAccountHandles(context).get(simNumber))

context.startActivity(intent);
```

Here  is a class for sim slot helper which will get phone account handle list by using telecom manager for both sims

**code:**

```
public class SimSlotHelper {
public static List getAccountHandles(Context context) {
    Class c;
    Method m;
    TelecomManager telecomManager;
    List<PhoneAccountHandle> accountHandles;
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {

        c = Class.forName("android.telecom.TelecomManager");
        Method m1 = c.getMethod("from", Context.class);
        telecomManager = (TelecomManager) m1.invoke(null, context);
        m = c.getMethod("getCallCapablePhoneAccounts");
        accountHandles = (List<PhoneAccountHandle>) m.invoke(telecomManager);
        return accountHandles;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .ACTION_DIAL instead of .ACTION_CALL . This opens a Dialog chooser with apps installed in the device with capability of calling.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't open Dialog Choose, And then it doesn't call directly. It open call screen, choose sim 1 or sim 2.

Comment: @Tr.Buu it opens a Dialer if there is no other calling Apps installed in the mobile or else it will open a Dialog picker with installed calling apps.